# bootstrap position of the doctype

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, doctype

As it is said in the Bootstrap web site, an HTML document structure must be like this 
(http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  ...
</html>
```

But I noticed that, this causes one problem, that an input height is greater than usual, it becomes normal just when I remove the doctype declaration.

how to explain this ?

Comment: doctype describes which html standard html page is using, so it can be that different html standarts uses a bit different css. I advise you alvays set css properties for all elements

Comment: when no doctype is declared , then which one is used ?

Comment: Without a Doctype you get Quirks mode, AKA "That inconsistent nightmare".

Comment: what sorts of problems , may i face ? , different behaviours from one brower to an other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that it's default behavior that you can't do anything about when you use the HTML5 doctype.

You could use an CSS Reset to clear out any default formatting that browsers/doctypes create for your elements.  Here is a pretty commonly used one, although it doesn't include anything for the input tag.: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
For the input size specifically, you could try some css like this:

```
input {
    height:30px;
}
```

Or whatever height you want it to be.  Let me know if I'm going in the wrong direction here.